# Prove that $g(x) = \dfrac{\int_x^T y(v) (v - x)^r dv}{(T''-x)^r}$ decreases for an arbitrary non-negative $y(v)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis

Let $g(x) = \dfrac{\int_x^T y(v) (v - x)^r dv}{(T''-x)^r}$,
where 
$0 \leq T'< T < T'' \leq 1, r \in Z_{+}$, $x \in [T',T]$ and $y(v) \geq 0$ for $v \in [T',T]$ -- an arbitrary non-negative function.

Prove that $g(x)$ decreases on $[T',T]$ or give a counterexample.

My hypothesis is that this fact is true and moreover if $y(v)$ is decreasing then $g(x)$ is concave, if  $y(v)$ is increasing $g(x)$ is convex.

P.S. $y$ depends only on $v$.